# Using incomplete web designs in a portfolio

Tags: website-design, website-templates, client-relations, mockup

I have battled a situation in the past from when I have an idea for a website I would design it. A few years back I decided to apply for some companies that were starting out in web development and posted they were seeking designers.  So I created a portfolio tailored to each employer and my understanding of a good portfolio was for it to not be overwhelming and to prepare no more than my ten best designs.  While on one of the interviews I was told, "we like your designs but wish they were full functioning sites".   So my questions are:

1. Is it a bad idea to use web designs that aren't coded?
2. How do you properly sell the design to a possible employer?
3. Is it bad to be honest that the designs are your ideas or should you pass them off as possible clients?
4. Is their a good balance to use in client work VS personal work?
5. Is a template design considered as personal work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a bad idea to use web designs that aren't coded?

No.

> How do you properly sell the design to a possible employer?

You sell the design as you would selling it to a customer. You explain how the approach you took met the project's objectives and goals.

> Is it bad to be honest that the designs are your ideas or should you pass them off as possible clients?

Not to be cliche, but: honesty is usually the best policy (at least in job interviews).

> Is their a good balance to use in client work VS personal work?

No particular rule. Show what you want to show and feels best represents your skills and styles.

> Is a template design considered as personal work?

I don't think there is any rule about that.